# Determine formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

a. How much will you invest each year? Even $\$50$ a month is a start ($\$600$ a year), you’ll be surprised at how much it will earn. You can chose a number you think you can afford on your life circumstances or you can dream big.

The typical example of a retirement investment is an I.R.A., an Individual Retirement Account, although other options are available. However, for this example, we will assume that you are investing in an I.R.A $8\%$ interest compounded annually.

b. Determine the formula for the accumulated amount that you will have saved for retirement as a function of time and be sure to simplify it as much as possible. You need to be able to show me what you used for $r$, $n$, and $P$ so that I can calculate your answers. Plug in those values into the formula and simplify the equation.

I cant figure out how to complete part B I want to use P $\$100$ a month for $1200$ a year at a rate of R= $.08$

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to  approach this, the easiest way is use a simple discrete formula since your interest rate is also discrete.
So $u_n=1.08u_{n-1}+1200$ with $u_0=1200$